# How to empty JTextField if gained focus

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield

I am new to java GUI and I have 2 `JTextField`'s `txtMessage1` and `txtMessage2`. I'd like to archive this: if one textfiled has focus the other one will be emptied, is that possible and how to archive it?

I tried:

```
if (txtMessage1.isFocusOwner())
    txtMessage2.setText("");
if (txtMessage2.isFocusOwner())
    txtMessage1.setText("");
```

But it doesn't work, not throwing anything....

Comment: Look into [writing focus listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [`FocusListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html) for it, like this:

```java
FocusAdapter fl = new FocusAdapter()
{
    public void focusGained (FocusEvent evt)
    {
        if (evt.getSource() == txtField1)
            txtField2.setText("");
        else if (evt.getSource() == txtField2)
            txtField1.setText("");
    }
}
txtField1.addFocusListener(fl);
txtField2.addFocusListener(fl);
```

Comment: how do I make your code in a method in my current class, not in a separate class like this?

Comment: @RonaldinhoState I edited the question, you now have an anonymos inner type. You can use this code inside your Method/Constructor

Comment: did you mean addFocusListener not setFocusListener right?

Comment: @RonaldinhoState Yes, I meant that, sorry

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a `FocusListener` for each `JTextField` or one single for both.

See the example at the bottom of this page:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html